# ''source of people's income" VS "source of people's incomes"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Employment is a major source of people's **income**.
> 2. Employment is a major source of people's **incomes**.

If I want to say working is a major way for people to make pay, which one to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally say that either is acceptable. I wouldn't take issue if I read or heard either.

Looking at similar phrases by way of analogy, we might think it has to be **incomes**:

> "They made a habit of cutting off people's **heads**"
>
> "University really taxes people's **brains**"

But then,

> "Our company has gotten where it is because of people's **drive**"
>
> "We try not to insult people's **intelligence**"

We might say that a person has several *drives*, meaning different sorts of motivation, but if we talk about the personal characteristic of being *driven*, it's always singular. People who study how minds work can talk about us having several different intelligences, but the abstract property of a person remains singular even when dealing with lots of people.

You can read *income* in this case as either being a quantifiable property distinct to each person, in which case they each have their own income which is not inherent to them as a person and is clearly distinct from that of each other person, or you can think of *income* as a much more abstract property more in line with *drive* or *intelligence*. Because of this, it works either plural or singular in such a case.

Comment: I assume you meant to write *of cutting **off** people's* in the first example sentence. By the way, an interesting discussion about this (the supposed clear-cut (heh) case) can be found [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=286).

Comment: @userr2684291: feel free to edit it yourself when it's such an obvious typo :)

Comment: We cannot say people's head instead of heads because I know that every individual has his own head. So when we say people's income, as a non-native English speaker, I will think that you are talking about national income or something, and when we say people's incomes, I will interpret this as every one's income.